# WPF 2D array to array stack items

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Currently I have a 2d array which shows depth down one index, then the second shows how many items will be in the current depth. We can say for example each column will contain between 1-4 items.

I want to display each depth as a row with the number of items shown as columns.

I already have the usercontrol that will bind to the element and show it I'm just not sure how to bind into the 2d array and construct it.

I think I'll need some kind of iteration but I'm not sure if this is in line if mmvvm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not take the constructor of the control and use it to iterate over the array of binded items. Then use this binding to create as many children that are as needed from the second dimension end iterate down the tree

Comment: I have up voted but it wont take effect

Comment: I didn't down vote but I believe it was because this is not an answer but a comment as an answer. I realize you don't have enough points to comment but putting comment type responses in answers is going to get you some flak.